# Make 1-100 using 2 0 2 2

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

You may use the following:

- Addition [e.g. 2+2]
- Subtraction [e.g. 2-2]
- Multiplication [e.g. 2x2]
- Division [e.g. 2/2]
- Decimal point [e.g. 2+.2]
- Exponents [e.g. 2<sup>2</sup>] {tetration is NOT allowed}
- Square roots [e.g. sqrt(2)] {infinite roots sqrt(sqrt(sqrt…sqrt(2))))=1 is NOT allowed}
- Arbitrary roots [e.g. 0.2th root of 2]
- Factorial [e.g. (2+2)!]
- Double factorial [e.g. (2+2)!!]
- Parentheses [e.g. 2/(2+2)]
- Concatenation [e.g. 22+20] {2[0!]=21 is NOT allowed}
- Permutations [e.g. (2+2)P2]
- Combinations [e.g. (2+2)C2]

I’ve got all the numbers from 1-100, except for 54, 67, 68, 69, 79, 82, 83, 84, 86, 87, 93, 97

Comment: Is this an original puzzle?

Comment: @bobble This looks like a copy of a MSE question [How do I express 67, 69, 83, 84, 86, 87, 88, 93 with 2,0,2,2 only?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4115671/318073). Other than same operations, we also have details here like mentioning "infinite square roots" that were discussed there.

Comment: how should permutations and combinations work in forming a number?

Answer (score 4):

All remaining 12 numbers you listed are doable, only if you allow arbitrary "$.$" and "$!$" uses.

---

Allowing arbitrary decimal point $.\square$, then 3 of remaining 12 numbers are:

> $$\begin{array}{}54 &=& \sqrt{\text{}^{.(0!)}\sqrt[]{2}} + 22\\68 &=& (\sqrt{\text{}^{.(0!)}\sqrt[]{2}}+2) \times 2\\82 &=& ((2 \times 2)!! + .2) / .(0!)\end{array}$$

Additionally allowing repeated-decimals $.\dot{\square}$, then 7 of remaining 9 are:

> $$\begin{array}{}67 &=& \left(\left(\sqrt{(.2) ^ {-2}}\right)!! - (.\dot{(0!)})\right) / (.\dot{2}) \\79 &=& (.\dot{(0!)}) ^ {-2} - 2\\83 &=& (.\dot{(0!)}) ^ {-2} + 2 \\84 &=& (.\dot{(0!)}) ^ {-2} + \sqrt{2 / (.\dot{2})}  \\86 &=& (.\dot{(0!)}) ^ {-2} + \sqrt{(.2) ^ {-2}} \\87 &=& (.\dot{(0!)}) ^ {-2} + \left(\sqrt{2/(.\dot{2})}\right)! \\97 &=& \left(\left(\sqrt{2 / (.\dot{2})}\right)!\right)!! \times 2 + 0!\end{array}$$

Additionally allowing subfactorial  $!\square$, then 2 of remaining 2 are:

> $$\begin{array}{}69 &=& \left((0! / .2)!! + \sqrt{.\dot{(!2)}}\right) / (.\dot{2}) \\93 &=& (\text{}^{.2}\sqrt{2}-0!)/ \sqrt{.(\dot{!2})}\end{array}$$

---

I wrote a python program to solve this.

Comment: Btw, if you use the rules as I used them in this answer, then permutations and combinations are not needed for any of the [first 100 numbers](https://pastebin.com/raw/Y4kbPPi3).